# Valiant Hearts not dropping Steam trading cards

Tags: steam-trading-cards, valiant-hearts

I have completed the entire game of Valiant hearts but Steam still says that I have 3 card drops remaining. How do I get my cards?

Answer (score 3):

Card drops aren't connected with game completion, you need to play the game for some time (longer than 2 hours, usually about 5-6 hours) in order to get card drops.

Also, your if your account is limited (didn't spend 5$ yet), you'll not get any card drops.